# Flutter: Realmdb "Getter Schema isn't defined for the type Transaction"

Tags: database, mongodb, flutter

Am trying to connect my flutter app to realmdb using the sdk, I installed the packages needed, then created the model and generated the script using:

`flutter pub run realm generate --watch`

when I use this command `final realm = Realm(Configuration.local([Transaction.schema]));` in main.dart it tells me:

```
The getter 'schema' isn't defined for the type 'Transaction'.
Try importing the library that defines 'schema', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'schema'.dartundefined_getter
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import './classes/client_transaction.dart' as transaction;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:client/login.dart';
import 'package:client/register.dart';
import 'package:client/overview.dart';
import 'package:client/Home.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:client/classes/auth.dart';
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  final realm = Realm(Configuration.local([Transaction.schema]));
```

client_transaction.dart

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

part 'client_transaction.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _Transaction {
  late String uid;
  late String name;
  late String category;
  late double amount;
  late String date;
}
```

the `'client_transaction.g.dart'` file was generated successfully.

I tried changing the name of the file, and regenerating the scripts but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by opening the realm inside the `client_transaction.dart` file and then calling the method from `main.dart`.

`client_transaction.dart:`

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

part 'client_transaction.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _Transaction {
  late String uid;
  late String name;
  late String category;
  late double amount;
  late String date;
}

init() {
  var config = Configuration.local([Transaction.schema]);
  var realm = Realm(config);
  var t = Transaction("123", "TestName", "food", 55.1, "13/13/2013");
  realm.write(() {
    realm.add(t);
  });
  var z= realm.all<Transaction>();
  Transaction x= z[0];
}
```

`main.dart:`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:client/classes/client_transaction.dart' as transactions;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:client/login.dart';
import 'package:client/register.dart';
import 'package:client/overview.dart';
import 'package:client/Home.dart';
// import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:client/classes/auth.dart';
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  transactions.init();
```